# What is the meaning of verb "court" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in a chapter named "Indigo" which was:

> Then he took a piece of paper and divided the group into pairs and put down the order in which each pair was to court arrest.

I can't really figure out which context has the verb "court" been used in here. Most of its definitions didn't help.

Comment: Interesting. I wanna know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the "try to get" sense, second verb one, in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/court). Or the next one, regarding risk; it could be read either way, and I really don't see the two as being entirely distinct.

*To court arrest* is to do things with the aim of getting arrested, or that one might expect to lead to arrest.

Answer (score 1):

This is the meaning used here:

> **court**
>   verb
>
> to risk something unpleasant, especially by behaving
>   stupidly or carelessly:
>
> *Drinking and driving is simply courting disaster.*

[Court (Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/court)

A person might court arrest by making a habit of stealing, or driving too fast.

Comment: So would "court arrest" be a phrasal verb?

Comment: 'Court arrest' is not a phrasal verb, which is a verb that is made up of a main verb together with an adverb or a preposition, or both. Typically, their meaning is not obvious from the meanings of the individual words themselves. 'Court' is a verb, and 'arrest' is a noun, and they have their ordinary, obvious meanings.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment.